# Send POST request by PhantomJS

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I need to send a post request using phantomjs webdriver, or change one field in post data(how to change i dont know) "jsenabled=false" sent phantomjs, "jsenabled=true" sent browser, i need to send "jsenabled=true" using phantomjs

```
_driver.Url = "https://connect.secure.wellsfargo.com/auth/login/presentorigin=cob&error=yes";
_driver.FindElementById("j_username").SendKeys(Username);
_driver.FindElementById("j_password").SendKeys(Password);
_driver.FindElementById("j_password").SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a question at all?!?